# Iterate IDictionary<string, string> with dynamic nested JSON as value in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net, dynamic-programming

My application receives Kafka messages that contain a `Dictionary<string,string>` as one of the properties, and its values could be a nested (however dynamic) json string, and I need to iterate through this unknown json. I am struggling to find a logic and even the best data structure to do this iteration.

Examples of the dictionary (mocked data):

```
//could have complex nested json string as value
"reward":"{
  'xp':'200', 
  'gp':'150', 
  'loot':'{
    'item':'sword',
    'rarity': 'low'
  }'
}",
"achievement":"win_match"

// while other messages might be simple
"type":"generic_xp",
"percent":"100",
"status":"complete"
```

Serialized version of a real message:

```
"{\"player_stats\":\"{\\\"assist\\\":0,\\\"deaths\\\":0,\\\"kills\\\":0,\\\"team_index\\\":2}\",\"round_attr\":\"{\\\"max_player_count\\\":4,\\\"rdur\\\":0,\\\"round\\\":1,\\\"team_player_count\\\":{\\\"team_1\\\":1,\\\"team_2\\\":0},\\\"team_score\\\":0}\",\"custom\":\"{\\\"armor\\\":\\\"armor_pickup_lv2\\\",\\\"balance\\\":550,\\\"helmet\\\":\\\"helmet_pickup_lv2\\\",\\\"misc\\\":[{\\\"count\\\":48,\\\"item_id\\\":\\\"shotgun\\\"},{\\\"count\\\":120,\\\"item_id\\\":\\\"bullet\\\"},{\\\"count\\\":2,\\\"item_id\\\":\\\"health_pickup_combo_small\\\"},{\\\"count\\\":2,\\\"item_id\\\":\\\"health_pickup_health_small\\\"}],\\\"weapon_1\\\":\\\"mp_weapon_semipistol\\\",\\\"weapon_2\\\":\\\"mp_weapon_shotgun_pistol\\\"}\",\"gdur\":\"0\"}"
```

**To complicate even more**

- Create a model class is not an option because this json is completely dynamic
- Flatting the dictionary is not possible because the json may have duplicated key names, but under different hierarchy
- I cant request to change the Kafka message

**What I am trying to do**

The end user will define rules that I need to check if I find a match. For instance, a rule could be `reward.xp == 200` or `reward.loot.rarity == high` or `status == complete`. These rules will be defined by the user so it cant be hardcoded, however I can decide with data structure to use to save them. So for each Kafka message, I have to iterate through that dictionary and try to find a match with the rules.

**What I have tried**

I ve tried `JsonConvert.Deserialize` to `object`, `dynamic`, `ExpandoObject` and none could handle the nested json hierarchy. They just got the 1st level correct. Same result with `JObject.Parse` as well.

Comment: why insist deserialize to concret type if json string is dynamic? what about just hold the jsonobject and get any data you want? and since you tagged .net core, will you use built in json library?

Comment: json.net should handle this fine with JObject.Parse. To iterate, you'll need to do a recursive visit of the nodes in the tree. If you need to you could then flatten this to a list - use the full path of keys to the node as the key in the list (e.g. `reward.loot.rarity`).

Comment: what does "duplicated key names, but under different hierarchy" mean?  Can you give an example of that?

Comment: @BrianRogers for instance `reward` can be in the root, as the example above, but it may also be under `achievement.reward`. So if I flat the structure, I get error for duplicated key.

Comment: @andrew `JObject.Parse` only parsed the first level correctly. In the reward example, I get the children `xp` and `gp` correctly, but for `loot`, instead of having children, it kept the string value. So in the example, `loot` property becomes a string prop which is value is a escaped string similar to the serialized example

Comment: @LeiYang I am using .NET Core 5. I dont have any restrictions in term of library. I may not have understood your suggestion, but it is not possible to solve the problem having just one string. I need hierarchy, the users will set rules with hierarchy.

Comment: have you tried jsonpath?

Comment: @TiagoBrenck - What does "this json is completely dynamic" mean? Like there's no structure?

Comment: @Enigmativity we currently have 43 possible structures, and within the 43, some props are not mandatory. These structures also get new props from time to time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the JSON using whatever parser you like (I used Newtonsoft.Json).

Then recursively visit the hierarchy and copy each property to a flat list using the full path to each property value as a key. You can then iterate that flat list.

**Edit:** Comment requested supporting arrays, so this version does.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/6ykHT0

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = @"{
                        'reward': { 
                            'xp': '200', 
                            'gp': '150', 
                            'loot': {
                                'item': 'sword',
                                'rarity': 'low',
                                'blah': {
                                    'socks': 5
                                }
                            },
                            'arrayofint': [1,2,3,4],
                            'arrayofobj': [
                                {
                                    'foo': 'bar',
                                    'stuff': ['omg!', 'what?!']
                                },
                                {
                                    'foo': 'baz',
                                    'stuff': ['a', 'b']
                                }
                            ],
                            'arrayofarray': [
                                [1,2,3],
                                [4,5,6]
                            ],
                            'arrayofheterogenousjunk': [
                                'a',
                                2,
                                { 'objprop': 1 },
                                ['staahp!']
                            ]
                        },
                        'achievement': 'win_match'
                    }";
        
        JObject data = JObject.Parse(json);
        IList<string> nodes = flattenJSON(data);
        
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, nodes));
    }
    
    private static IList<string> flattenJSON(JToken token)
    {
        return _flattenJSON(token, new List<string>());
    }

    private static IList<string> _flattenJSON(JToken token, List<string> path)
    {
        var output = new List<string>();
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            // Output the object's child properties
            output.AddRange(token.Children().SelectMany(x => _flattenJSON(x, path)));
        }
        else if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            // Output each array element
            var arrayIndex = 0;
            foreach (var child in token.Children())
            {
                // Append the array index to the end of the last path segment - e.g. someProperty[n]
                var newPath = new List<string>(path);
                newPath[newPath.Count - 1] += "[" + arrayIndex++ + "]";
                output.AddRange(_flattenJSON(child, newPath));
            }
        }
        else if (token.Type == JTokenType.Property)
        {
            var prop = token as JProperty;
            // Insert the property name into the path
            output.AddRange(_flattenJSON(prop.Value, new List<string>(path) { prop.Name }));
        }
        else
        {
            // Join the path segments delimited with periods, followed by the literal value
            output.Add(string.Join(".", path) + " = " + token.ToString());
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
reward.xp = 200
reward.gp = 150
reward.loot.item = sword
reward.loot.rarity = low
reward.loot.blah.socks = 5
reward.arrayofint[0] = 1
reward.arrayofint[1] = 2
reward.arrayofint[2] = 3
reward.arrayofint[3] = 4
reward.arrayofobj[0].foo = bar
reward.arrayofobj[0].stuff[0] = omg!
reward.arrayofobj[0].stuff[1] = what?!
reward.arrayofobj[1].foo = baz
reward.arrayofobj[1].stuff[0] = a
reward.arrayofobj[1].stuff[1] = b
reward.arrayofarray[0][0] = 1
reward.arrayofarray[0][1] = 2
reward.arrayofarray[0][2] = 3
reward.arrayofarray[1][0] = 4
reward.arrayofarray[1][1] = 5
reward.arrayofarray[1][2] = 6
reward.arrayofheterogenousjunk[0] = a
reward.arrayofheterogenousjunk[1] = 2
reward.arrayofheterogenousjunk[2].objprop = 1
reward.arrayofheterogenousjunk[3][0] = staahp!
achievement = win_match
```

**PREVIOUS VERSION (NO ARRAY SUPPORT)**

This doesn't properly support arrays - it will output the contents of a property that is an array as the raw JSON - i.e. it won't traverse into the array.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/yZbwul

```
public static void Main()
{
    string json = @"{
                    'reward': { 
                        'xp': '200', 
                        'gp': '150', 
                        'loot': {
                            'item': 'sword',
                            'rarity': 'low',
                            'blah': {
                                'socks': 5
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    'achievement': 'win_match'
                }";
    
    JObject data = JObject.Parse(json);
    IList<string> nodes = flattenJSON(data, new List<string>());
    
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, nodes));
}

private static IList<string> flattenJSON(JObject obj, IList<string> path)
{
    var output = new List<string>();
    foreach (var prop in obj.Properties())
    {
        if (prop.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            output.AddRange(flattenJSON(prop.Value as JObject, new List<string>(path){prop.Name}));
        }
        else
        {
            var s = string.Join(".", new List<string>(path) { prop.Name }) + " = " + prop.Value.ToString();
            output.Add(s);
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

**Output:**

```
reward.xp = 200
reward.gp = 150
reward.loot.item = sword
reward.loot.rarity = low
reward.loot.blah.socks = 5
achievement = win_match
```

Comment: can you also add some list (values) sample?

Comment: @LeiYang - do you mean a property whose value is an array?

Comment: yes. you have solved nested key very well, and one key feature left is array value.

Comment: @LeiYang - not sure if OP needed that, but I was bored. Now supports arrays :)

Comment: @andrew I updated my question and added a real Json string there. Could you help me understand why the `JObject` is not parsing the children?

Comment: I'm happy to help but for now, can you check the fiddle?

Comment: @andrew no rush. I checked and replaced your jsonString with the example and only 4 properties got parsed. The others: assists, deaths, kills etc, where recognized as string instead of JProperty. I think this is what is blocking me from using the examples I found online, and even yours. Btw, the flatting function looks amazing, it will be so handy! Thanks buddy

Comment: @TiagoBrenck Your example JSON is not valid. The child objects are incorrectly surrounded by double quotes. That is telling the parser to treat those objects as strings.

Comment: @andrew that is the result of `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` for the Kafka message. I believe I will have to manually convert it to a json string then. If the message is in the wrong format, I cant request them to change, unfortunately.

Comment: @TiagoBrenck - I'm not familiar with the library. Maybe ask a separate question about why the child objects are wrapped in quotes and how to deserialize in C#. I would hope there's an existing way to do this simply, rather than having to deal with it manually (either at serialization, or deserialization time).

Comment: @andrew I found a fix for the invalid JSON. The dictionary on Kafka messages will wrap nested Json in a string, so the built-in converters think that the string is just a value instead of a new Json. So to make your brilliant solution to work with this annoying message format, I had to add this ```else if(token.Type == JTokenType.String && token.ToString().StartsWith("{"))
            {
                var jObj = JObject.Parse(token.ToString());
                output.AddRange(jObj.Children().SelectMany(x => _FlattenJSON(x, path)));
            }```